# How to get a text from a tag that do not have ID or Class

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract "Movie" text from this snippet using JSOUP :
[image]

As you can notice, the second span tag does not have ID or class neither, besides the first span. My question is how can I retrieve that text ?

Thank you.

```
<span>                                                             
</span><span><span class="contentTitle">
Program Type:</span>
<span style="font-size: 14px;">
Movie</span>
<br />
</span><span id="MainContent_trProgramCategories"><span class="contentTitle">
 Categories:</span>&nbsp; 
<span style="font-size: 14px;">Horror, Thriller
</span>
```

Comment: Please always post your HTML snippet as text, not as an image.

Comment: I'm not 100% about JSOUP, but I normally use an XPath query.  I'm pretty sure that JSoup has its own query language, but basically you want to use the "path" to the element as part of the uniquiness.  But it might still return multiple results...ie "find me the span element that is a child of .../table/tbody/tr/td/span"

Comment: And move is contained within an element with a class of "contentTitle". It is nested in another element, but this information will help you if used correctly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I thought that it'll be clearer when making a screenshot of it.

Comment: @androniennn But then we can't test it :P

Comment: @androniennn: you tell me which is easier for folks to test on their own computers? An image or the actual testable text?

Comment: You need to show the whole table, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Element element = doc.select("#MainContent_trProgramCategories  .contentTitle").get(0).nextElementSibling();
```

Comment: That works for `MainContent_trProgramCategories`, but in my case I want to retrieve "Movies" from a span that not have any identifier. please read my question. Thank you.

Comment: This worked finally: `document.select("span.contentTitle").get(0).nextElementSibling().text();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep whittling down the data by playing with the `select(...)` method. For instance, simply doing:

```
Elements myEles = doc.select("div[id=MainContent_UpdatePanel2] td");
String text = myEles.text();

System.out.println(text);
```

Will get you most of the stuff you're likely interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" suggested.

For future use cases though,
the easiest way to get the CSS path or XPath for an element is to use Firebug extension.

[image: Firebug extension]

You can click the "mouse pointer looking icon" next to the "bug looking image" and choose the element that you want to retrieve the value from the browser and then the next row's XPath/CSS text box will give you the path that you can use.

Simply copy that text and paste it in the code

```
doc.select("HERE PASTE THE XPATH/CSS PATH THAT YOU COPIED FROM FIREBUG").text();
```

If you are using chrome,

you can

1. right-click on an element that you want to retrieve the text value
   from
2. choose "Inspect Element"
3. right-click again on the highlighted element in the debugger
4. choose "Copy XPath"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but FireBug gives me an Xpath that JSOUP can not "understand". In my example I have this `/html/body/form/center/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[4]/span[2]`

Comment: I'm really interested with your method.

Comment: According to http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax you can use CSS query to get the element that you need. Copy the css query instead of XPath and see how it goes